# Redux dev tool stopped working in chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, redux, ngrx

Redux dev tool chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) suddenly stopped working. Its logs the event but UI is just unresponsive and nothing is clickable. I thought there might be issue with my application but even I tried with [live demo app](http://zalmoxisus.github.io/examples/todomvc/) and its having the same issue.
[Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remotedev/) is working fine, I am not sure what I have did wrong. 
I have tried as below but nothing worked.

- Reinstalling the Redux dev chrome extension
- Reinstalling the Chrome
- Restarting the computer

[image]

I can use the Firefox addon for Redux debug but I am comfortable with chrome debugger. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should include versions of what you're using, how your `app.module.ts` looks like. From the information you've provided now, no one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. It's a known bug. I think you will need to wait until someone fix it.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/issues/379).

Comment: Just to inform, I found same issue sometime and it get resolved after some days might be due to the updates.